# How to access unreachable AWS instance?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS instance that suddenly **I've lost access both by SSH and to the web server there.**

I used to access by a public Elastic IP (54.76.201.91), so I know for sure that Security Groups are ok. Now that IP doesn't respond, ssh port is closed, also port 80.

If I press **Get System Log** I can see:

[image: Get System Log capture]

As I can see IP **169.254.169.254** I think there is a DHCP problem.

You can see full log [here](http://pastebin.com/A16zNixr)

What I have tried unsucessfully?

- Reattach new Elastic IP
- Connected by browser Java SSH Client
- Create AMI (it worked) and start new instance with a new Elastic IP

So my question is

**Is there any other way to connect?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming this is EBS backed you can stop the instance, mount the EBS as a secondary volume on another functioning EC2 instance, fix whatever you need to fix then assign it back to a separate instance.