# Can AWS simluate direct console login (eg, if sshd doesn't work)

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) (Amazon Web Services) provide a way to log simluate logging directly into the computer -- as if I was using a keyboard plugging into the server itself? For example, if sshd was configured incorrectly and didn't work when I rebooted my computer, can I go through the aws website and simulate logging in directly via my web browser?

Linode accomplishes this with ["Lish"](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/using-the-linode-shell-lish)

Comment: FWIW you can still recover your instance without being able to log into it: https://serverfault.com/questions/632968/how-to-access-unreachable-aws-instance/632975#632975

Comment: Digitalocean has it, and I believe Azure has it too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they do not.

They could easily do so, but, they have not yet implemented it. I believe that this is an intentional design decision they have made to encourage their customers to use automated provisioning and proper HA setups where one does not need to sign into individual servers to perform recovery - instead the unhealthy instance is just destroyed and another created to replace it.

Comment: I guess it's a different frame of mind. You can't treat AWS instances like normal servers.

Comment: @ewwhite Yup, agreed. Many people try to do so, but it's sub-optimal in nearly every way to do so. If one wants "a server", AWS is likely not the right provider.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS it's not possible.
You will have to either throw away and terminate your instance or contact AWS support.

Comment: Throwing away your instance isn't necessary. One can easily attach the root vol to another running instance and sort out the improper configuration. Second, AWS support isn't going to be able to help with OS issues within your instance, as they don't have that level of access to your systems. The most they'll do is suggest performing recovery as I mentioned